# Sample size estimation for an Instrumental Variable Study

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, instrumental-variables

I'm designing pretty much a textbook instrumental variable study. Paraphrasing the actually set-up, we're planning to offer in-store discount coupons and trying to assess whether providing coupons is a good idea.

Given there will be a clear self selection involved (more loyal customers will opt in to more discounts) we're sending a mailer with discount to a random subset of customers and a mailer with no discount to the control. Assuming that we have a strong first stage, I'll estimate the true effect size of incremental discount via a 2SLS.

However, in this scenario, how can I decide how many people to send the mailers to so that I have a sufficiently powered experiment?

Comment: Have you run mailer campaigns before to get a sense of take-up?

Comment: If you mean to ask what's the response rate, then yes. It's like 70%+

Answer (score 1):

There is a paper by [Walker et al (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1093/ije/dyx090) that discusses this power calculation [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5837396/).

They also have [a web calculator](https://venexia.shinyapps.io/PharmIV/), as well as [Stata and R code](https://github.com/venexia/PharmIV).

---

Walker, V. M., Davies, N. M., Windmeijer, F., Burgess, S., & Martin, R. M. (2017). Power calculator for instrumental variable analysis in pharmacoepidemiology. International journal of epidemiology, 46(5), 1627–1632. https://doi.org/10.1093/ije/dyx090

Comment: @user319791 Does this make sense?